# Autocomplete multiple value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdo

I've completed the question before. However I got another issue. I want to make multiple autocomplete like https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple .
I've include function into my script but still doesn't work.

This is html email form code

```
   <div class="input_container">
    <input type="text" id="contact_id" name="sender" onkeyup="autocomplet()" size="95">
    <input type="hidden" id="client_id" value="<?php echo $id_client; ?>">
<ul id="contact_list"></ul>
```

This javascript script

```
function autocomplet() {
var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
var keyword = $('#contact_id').val();
var cid = $('#client_id').val();
if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_email_refresh.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "keyword="+keyword+"&cid="+cid+"",
        success:function(data){
            $('#contact_list').show();
            $('#contact_list').html(data);
                 focus: function() {
                  // prevent value inserted on focus
                  return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                  var terms = split( this.value );
                  // remove the current input
                  terms.pop();
                  // add the selected item
                  terms.push( ui.item.value );
                  // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                  terms.push( "" );
                  this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                  return false;
                  }
        }
    });
    } else {
    $('#contact_list').hide();
 }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
// change input value
$('#contact_id').val(item);
// hide proposition list
$('#contact_list').hide();
}
```

ajax_email_refresh code

```
    $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
    $cid = $_POST['keyword2'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact_name LIKE (:keyword) AND id_client = (:cid) ORDER BY contact_id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $list = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($list as $rs) {
     // put in bold the written text
     $contact_name = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['contact_email']);
     // add new option
     echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['contact_email']).'\')">'.$contact_name.'</li>';
   }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The autocomplete doesn't show. If I just input one value (contact_id) it works

Comment: So you want the autocomplete to work for the second input as well?

Comment: Yeah, two input at same time because the id_client is hidden type

Comment: So if I get you right, want that if you choose an item from the auto complete, it will set it as the value of both of the inputs?

Comment: Can we see you're 'ajax_email_refresh.php'

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the data which is returned?

Comment: @MorHaviv I want to see the email value from two input, name and id_client

Comment: You have to post more of your code.

Comment: @Ibanez the example is we type the name, and the autocomplete will show the email value based from name and id_client

Comment: After you send the POST data to ajax_email_refresh.php, what does it return?

Comment: @MorHaviv It will show the contact_email

Comment: So what input do you want to echo the email? In the form you posted there are only 2 inputs

Comment: @MorHaviv name and id client, name we must type but the id_client value we get from hyperlink and echo in id_client

Comment: Yes I get it, what I don't get is after we finished it and we filled the id_client and we filled the name we got the email from ajax_email_refresh.php. Now after we got the user's email address, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @MorHaviv After that we will sent an email. So user don't need to put sender name manually but just type few words, the autocomplete will get the sender name from database

Comment: I am really sorry but I can't help you. You have to improve you English and explain everything from the begining because I did not understand what this page is

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly what you are looking for. I have included an example that will help you get started. The timer I have included is to minimize the amount of ajax request you will be doing. Instead of making a request on after every single key stroke, it actually waits 250 milliseconds after the last stroke has been made to run your ajax.

```js
var object = [{'key': 'value1'}, {'key': 'value2'}];
var timer;
function autocompletion(element){
 clearTimeout(timer);
 timer = setTimeout(function(){
  var options = element.nextElementSibling;
        options.innerHTML = '';
      
  for(var i = 0; i < object.length; ++i){
   var li = document.createElement('li');
   li.innerHTML = object[i]['key'];
   options.appendChild(li);
  }
  options.style.display = 'block';
 }, 250);
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
<input type="hidden" id="id_client" name="id_client" value="<?php echo $id_client; ?>">
<input type="text" id="contact_id" name="sender" onkeyup="autocompletion(this)" size="95">
<ul id="contact_list" style='display: none'></ul>
```